# jQuery UI widgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

What jQuery UI widgets are there, except from the official ones?

I know

- Accordion
- Autocomplete
- Button
- Datepicker
- Dialog
- Progressbar
- Slider
- Tabs

Comment: There is no finite answer to this question. Anyone can create plugins/widgets for jQueryUI. Why do you need such a list anyway?

Comment: I want to make my site as easy as possible for the users. Widgets are an simple way to make it easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of plugins are available on the jquery website:

http://plugins.jquery.com/

If you need a specific one, the only way to find them is to search for it with a search engine(ex: jquery checkbox, jquery selectmenu, jquery tooltip ...).

[Checkbox](http://www.openpave.org/~reg/jqueryui-checkbox.html)

[Selectmenu](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/)

[Tooltip](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/)

Answer (score 2):

Theres to many to name, this question is very broad and you should do some research before asking a question like this.

specifically talking about the jQuery built one's then you should look at the download section: http://jqueryui.com/download

But in regards to user built ones you just need to look around the web and do a few searches. theres no way to get a list of ALL of the user built ones.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a [Multiple Select Widget](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/)